# How to convert SQL query values separated comma to list by using entity framework core 7?

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework-core, linq-to-entities

I work on asp.net core razor page . I face issue How to convert complicated sql query to entity framework core 7

Exactly I need to convert this SQL statement to LINQ to entity without write SQL statement on csharp meaning i need to use code first entity framework core 7

function below get values separated comma and convert it to list based on related Print server .

```
 public DataTable GetBranchesRelatedToServer(string PrintServer)
        {
               DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                
                cmd.CommandText = ";with cte as (SELECT distinct PrintServer,REPLACE (Split.A.value('.', 'VARCHAR(4000)') , ' ', '' ) as BranchId FROM  (SELECT BranchCode, PrintServer,CAST ('<M>' + REPLACE(BranchCode, ',', '</M><M>') + '</M>' AS XML) AS String   FROM  [dbo].[tbl_branchPDFexe]) AS A CROSS APPLY String.nodes ('/M') AS Split(A)) select t.PrintServer,t.BranchId,b.vBranchDesc from  cte t inner join [dbo].[tbl_Branch] b with(nolock) on t.BranchId=b.iBranchCode and PrintServer=@PrintServer";
                
            
            return dt;
        }
```

when models used is

```
[Table("tbl_branchPDFexe")]
    public class BranchPDFexe
    {
       public decimal Id { get; set; }
       public string BranchCode { get; set; }
       public string PrintServer { get; set; }
    }

[Table("tbl_Branch")]
    public class Branch
    {
        [Key]
        public string iBranchCode { get; set; }
        public string vBranchDesc { get; set; }

    }
```

Data input before query run on table `tbl_branchPDFexe`

[image: input before split]

Table structure `tbl_Branch`

[image: branches table]

Expected result will be

[image: result after split]

so code will be after convert it to entity framework core

```
 public list GetBranchesRelatedToServer(string PrintServer)
            {
dbcontext.BranchPDFexe.where().join(branch)
// so How to make it by linq to entity 
                   return list
            }
```

**updated post**

as you say .NET core 7 don't support CTE with xml

can you show to me available ways can do it by using entity framework core 7

updated post
can you please help me to apply this logic

1-return list of BranchCode without comma separated from table BranchPDFexe

2-join with table Branch to get branchName
so no need to depend on sql

So How to do these steps please

**Update Post**

can you please help me to solve issue without using sql query
as below

```
var distinctBranchCodesAndPrintServers = _adc.BranchPDFexe
     .SelectMany(b => b.BranchCode.Split(new[] { ',' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
         .Select(bc => new { BranchCode = bc.Trim(), b.PrintServer }));
```

but i get error

```
System.InvalidOperationException: 'The LINQ expression 'b => b.BranchCode.Split(
separator: char[] { , },
options: RemoveEmptyEntries)
.AsQueryable()
     .Distinct()
     .ToList();
```

**Update Post**

sql statment

```
cmd.CommandText = ";with cte as (SELECT distinct PrintServer,REPLACE (Split.A.value('.', 'VARCHAR(4000)') , ' ', '' ) as BranchId FROM  (SELECT BranchCode, PrintServer,CAST ('<M>' + REPLACE(BranchCode, ',', '</M><M>') + '</M>' AS XML) AS String   FROM  [dbo].[tbl_branchPDFexe]) AS A CROSS APPLY String.nodes ('/M') AS Split(A)) select t.PrintServer,t.BranchId,b.vBranchDesc from  cte t inner join [dbo].[tbl_Branch] b with(nolock) on t.BranchId=b.iBranchCode and PrintServer=@PrintServer";
```

statement above split branch code from table BranchPDFexe to list of

numbers then join with table tbl_branches to get `VBranchDesc`

so BranchCode have 10206,10207,101lc01 for print server 10 will be

```
10206   10
10207   10
101lc01 10
```

and after that join with table tbl_branches to get vbranchDesc so it will be

```
10206    Jumira           10  
10207    Al Aweer         10
101lc01  MalCamp- Alquoz  10
```

so final Statement will be

```
PrinterServer iBranchCode VBranchDesc
```

Comment: You  can't. `CTE (WITH)`, `AS XML`, `with(nolock)` are not supported by EF Core.

Comment: so how apply this logic on ef core 7  ";with cte as (SELECT distinct PrintServer,REPLACE (Split.A.value('.', 'VARCHAR(4000)') , ' ', '' ) as BranchId FROM  (SELECT BranchCode, PrintServer,CAST ('<M>' + REPLACE(BranchCode, ',', '</M><M>') + '</M>' AS XML) AS String   FROM  [dbo].[tbl_branchPDFexe]) AS A CROSS APPLY String.nodes ('/M') AS Split(A)) select t.PrintServer,t.BranchId,b.vBranchDesc from  cte t inner join [dbo].[tbl_Branch] b with(nolock) on t.BranchId=b.iBranchCode and PrintServer=@PrintServer";

Comment: I can repeat again. EF Core's LINQ do not support `CTE`, `AS XML` - leave raw SQL or create View.

Comment: ok so How to do it by any way without using ado.net and by use ef core code first

Comment: Can you show me another available wy to do that

Comment: you can use FromSqlRaw https://khalidabuhakmeh.com/recursive-data-with-entity-framework-core-and-sql-server#:~:text=Using%20CTEs%20With%20EF%20Core,of%20our%20EF%20entity's%20shape. https://www.learnentityframeworkcore.com/raw-sql

Comment: Or you can make a stored procedure or view, and bind an entity type to that

Comment: can you please show me if possible by code

Comment: I updated post can you check main thread please

Comment: Do you understand what the SQL is doing? Can you explain it to us?

Comment: I updated post you can check for summary i get branch code from table tbl_branchpdf  as 10206,10207 with printer server 10 then split them to list 10206 10 10207 10 then join with tbl_branch table to get name so finally i need to return list of printerserver with branchcode wirh vbranchdesc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll preface by saying: **your database design is fundamentally broken.** You should normalize the table out into separate rows..

---

You can use `STRING_SPLIT` in a raw query to get an `IQueryable<string>`, which you can then compose over to get the rest of the joins.

```cs
public static IQueryable<string> GetSplitBranchPdf(this YourDbContext db, string printServer)
{
    return db.Database.SqlQueryRaw<string>(@"
SELECT
  TRIM(v.value) AS Value
FROM dbo.tbl_branchPDFexe bpd
CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT(bpd.BranchCode, ',') v
WHERE bpd.PrintServer = @PrintServer
",
        new SqlParameter("@PrintServer", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 100) { Value = printServer }
    );
}

public async Task<List<MyResult>> GetBranchesRelatedToServer(string printServer)
{
    var splitBranches = Db.GetSplitBranchPdf(printServer);
    // must do this in a separate step, do not merge
    var results =
        from b in Db.Branch
        join t in splitBranches
          on t equals b.iBranchCode
        select new MyResult {
            PrintServer = printServer,
            BranchId = t.BranchId,
            vBranchDesc = b.vBranchDesc
        };
    return results.ToListAsync();
}
```

For raw queries returning a single scalar column we can use `db.Database.SqlQueryRaw`, and the column name must be `Value`. Otherwise we need to use a full entity with `db.Set<SomeEntity>.FromSqlRaw`.

Note that the first function returns an `IQueryable`. It does not run any anything until it's actually queried, which means it is composable.

Answer (score 0):

You have different ways, one way is to use FromSqlRaw

First, you have to define a class, but you work with the following
configuration so that the table is not created

define a class

```
public class vw_BranchPDFexe
{
    public string PrintServer { get; set; }
    public string BranchId { get; set; }
    public string vBranchDesc { get; set; }
}
```

configuration so that the table is not created

```
 protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

        modelBuilder.Ignore<vw_BranchPDFexe>();

        modelBuilder.Entity<vw_BranchPDFexe>().HasNoKey();
```

Run Query

```
var _result= 
context.vw_BranchPDFexe.FromSqlRaw(
        $";with cte as (SELECT distinct PrintServer,REPLACE (Split.A.value('.', 'VARCHAR(4000)') , ' ', '' ) as BranchId FROM  (SELECT BranchCode, PrintServer,CAST ('<M>' + REPLACE(BranchCode, ',', '</M><M>') + '</M>' AS XML) AS String   FROM  [dbo].[tbl_branchPDFexe]) AS A CROSS APPLY String.nodes ('/M') AS Split(A)) select t.PrintServer,t.BranchId,b.vBranchDesc from  cte t inner join [dbo].[tbl_Branch] b with(nolock) on t.BranchId=b.iBranchCode and PrintServer={PrintServer}"

).ToList();
```